# apt-get wants an older GNUTLS version to be defined

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 18.04, gnutls

Just upgraded to 18.04, and when I run `sudo apt update`, it complains:

> `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so: symbol gnutls_pkcs11_privkey_init version GNUTLS_3_4 not defined in file libgnutls.so.30 with link time reference
>   Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so`

Older info:

Running `gio version` gives: `2.53.6`

Running `gntls-cli -v` gives: `gnutls-cli 3.5.8`

As far as I can tell, this means that `apt-get` wants to use `GNUTLS version 3.4`, when I have `3.5.8`.

Any ideas on how to proceed would be appreciated. My suspicion is that perhaps it did not resolve the dependencies correctly when upgrading distros or is trying to update from the wrong repositories.

Interestingly, I get the same error when opening Octave (https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/).

---

Added in response to comment:

`apt-cache policy libgnutls30` says:

```
libgnutls30:
  Installed: 3.5.18-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.5.18-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.18-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30` points to `libgnutls.so.30.14.10` for me

`nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 | grep GNUTLS_3` prints `0000000000000000 A GNUTLS_3_4`

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy libgnutls30` say? My bionic system shows `gnutls-cli 3.5.18` however  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30` points to `libgnutls.so.30.14.10` and `nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 | grep GNUTLS_3` shows `GNUTLS_3_4`

Comment: Thanks, just added this info to the question--I am seeing the same output as you for those commands, although I don't know enough to understand what it means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I solved the issue. Note that it seemed a bit dangerous at the end, so a safer approach in another answer or in comments would be appreciated.

I found out there are two versions of `libgnutls.so.30` on my system, one in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and the other in `/usr/local/lib/`.

Running `nm -gC` and `readelf -sW` with `grep` on these files shows that the first one does contain the symbol in question and the second does not. This leads me to believe that the wrong copy of `gnutls` is being loaded at run time.

The file in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` is a link to `libgnutls.so.30.14.10`, and the one in `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` is a link to `libgnutls.so.30.13.1`.

Confirmation: Running `ldd` on `libgiognutls` shows that it does try to link to the `/usr/local/lib` version.

More confirmation: Changing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` did not work. Looking through the `ld.so` man page shows that this is probably because some elevated privilege is attained by the time ld.so is called.

Doing `sudo su` and then changing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. At this point, I am convinced that it is the link priorities of the two versions of `libgnutls` that is the issue.

Solved: I just took a leap of faith and linked the `/usr/local/lib/libgnutls.so` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so` file and the same with the `.30` versions as well. So far nothing has broken and the error messages are gone.