# GNUTLS version preventing LibreOffice from loading

Tags: 18.04, gnome, libreoffice, snap

I've run into the exact same issue as [apt-get wants an older GNUTLS version to be defined](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065651/apt-get-wants-an-older-gnutls-version-to-be-defined) when I attempt to run LibreOffice (`/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: symbol gnutls_srp_allocate_client_credentials version GNUTLS_3_4 not defined in file libgnutls.so.30 with link time reference`)...

...except a ton of extra libgnutls duplicates are apparently being generated by snap:

```
/snap/core/6673/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/core/6673/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
/snap/core/6818/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/core/6818/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
/snap/core/6964/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/core/6964/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
/snap/core18/782/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/core18/782/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10
/snap/core18/941/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/core18/941/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10
/snap/core18/970/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/core18/970/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/31/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/31/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/36/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/40/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/40/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10
/snap/libreoffice/116/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/libreoffice/116/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10
/snap/libreoffice/117/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/libreoffice/117/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10
/snap/libreoffice/118/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/snap/libreoffice/118/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10
/usr/local/lib/libgnutls.so.30
```

I feel like following the solution in the original post will address the symptoms of the issue but not the root; should I look at uninstalling and reinstalling snap first before I try to do any relinking? Or is something deeper going on here?

Comment: See answer below and if it fails, then please add output of `ldd /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin | grep "/usr/local"` to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such problems are usually caused by libraries in `/usr/local/lib`.

Try to move the problematic library out the way and retry to launch LibreOffice:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libgnutls.so.30 ~/
soffice
```

Also note that libraries in `/snap/` are isolated and usable only by the corresponding snapped application.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Though I am curious why `/snap/libreoffice/` has its own libgnutls when the program itself was referencing `/usr/local/lib`. Seems redundant.