# Failed to load module::libgiognutls.so

Tags: kernel, gnutls

After update gnutls at end `sudo apt-ger update'`this warning appears

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so: symbol gnutls_pkcs11_privkey_init version GNUTLS_3_4 not defined in file libgnutls.so.30 with link time reference
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so
```

and at boot system says my `/etc/profile` is wrong

```
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so | grep local 
libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/local/lib/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007fbc3b240000) 
libnettle.so.7 => /usr/local/lib/libnettle.so.7 (0x00007fbc39797000) 
libhogweed.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/libhogweed.so.5 (0x00007fbc39561000)
```

```
cat /etc/profile | grep LD 
gpaolo@gpaolo:~$
```

```
ls /usr/local/lib
libgnutls.la liblept.so.5.0.3 libX11-xcb.a libgnutls.so libmypaint-2.0.la
libX11-xcb.la libgnutls.so.30 libmypaint-2.0.so libX11-xcb.so 
libgnutls.so.30.25.0 libmypaint-2.0.so.0 libX11-xcb.so.1 
libgnutlsxx.la libmypaint-2.0.so.0.0.0 libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
libgnutlsxx.so libnettle.a pkgconfig libgnutlsxx.so.28
```

Comment: I would recommend to install `libgnutls28-dev` package and report any changes of the problem.

Comment: libgnutls28-dev installed on my linux ubuntu 18.04 64bit

Comment: Reinstall it along with other package by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall glib-networking libgnutls28-dev`.

Comment: done. But /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so: symbol gnutls_pkcs11_privkey_init version GNUTLS_3_4 not defined in file libgnutls.so.30 with link time reference
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so

Comment: the question proposed https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065651/apt-get-wants-an-older-gnutls-version-to-be-defined but I don't know how i can do.

Comment: Then please add output of `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so | grep local` , `ls /usr/local/lib` and `cat /etc/profile | grep LD` to the question.

Comment: ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so | grep local
 libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/local/lib/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007fbc3b240000)
 libnettle.so.7 => /usr/local/lib/libnettle.so.7 (0x00007fbc39797000)
 libhogweed.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/libhogweed.so.5 (0x00007fbc39561000)

Comment: cat /etc/profile | grep LD 
gpaolo@gpaolo:~$

Comment: comands ls /usr/local/lib is too long

Comment: a part libgnutls.la           liblept.so.5.0.3         libX11-xcb.a
libgnutls.so           libmypaint-2.0.la        libX11-xcb.la
libgnutls.so.30        libmypaint-2.0.so        libX11-xcb.so
libgnutls.so.30.25.0   libmypaint-2.0.so.0      libX11-xcb.so.1
libgnutlsxx.la         libmypaint-2.0.so.0.0.0  libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
libgnutlsxx.so         libnettle.a              pkgconfig
libgnutlsxx.so.28

Answer (score 3):

You have several TLS-related libraries in `/usr/local/lib`, in the normally configured system they should not be here. The APT installs libraries to `/lib`, `/usr/lib` and so on.

So you have to move the related libraries to home folder with:

```
mkdir ~/wrong_libs
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libgnutls* ~/wrong_libs/
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libnettle.so.7 ~/wrong_libs/
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libhogweed.so.5 ~/wrong_libs/
```

and then all should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. Idone and it's ok.